# AngularJS and Angular-Route-Segment

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am new to AngularJS so any tips will be welcome as I'm still trying to wrap my head around how everything works.

The following controller houses other controllers inside of it, however I've shortened the code to replicate my problem without the inner segments (I'll have more bugs once I add that in).

This is my html section:

```
<div  ng-app="app">
<div class="ng-cloak" ng-controller="mainController">
    <a ng-class="{active: ('sectionHome' | routeSegmentStartsWith)}" href="#{{'sectionHome' | routeSegmentUrl}}">Home</a>

    <div id="content" style="">
        <div app-view-segment="0"></div>
    </div>

    <div id=loading class=alert ng-show="loader.show">Loading...</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'route-segment', 'view-segment']);

app.config(function($routeSegmentProvider, $routeProvider) {

$routeSegmentProvider.options.autoLoadTemplates = true;

$routeSegmentProvider    
    .when('/Home', 'sectionHome')
    .segment('sectionHome', {
        'default': true,
        templateUrl: '../templates/sHome.html',
        controller: 'mainController'})             

$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/Home'}); 
}) ;

app.value('loader', {show: false});

app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $routeSegment, loader) {

$scope.$routeSegment = $routeSegment;
$scope.loader = loader;

$scope.$on('routeSegmentChange', function() {
    loader.show = false;
})
});
```

I'm either missing something conceptual or some other big thing, since when I inspect the link it appears that the scope bindings are not set in the html document and I remain with "ng-class="{active: ('sectionHome' | routeSegment...".

I've tried editing the code in jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/3boccdu6/) however there I'm receiving an error
"..[$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.."

This would make sense but I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've been following this working example:
http://angular-route-segment.com/src/example/#/section3

Comment: I'm going to try to rewrite from scratch without using the angular-route-segment module. Just the Angular route module. Still any comments would be welcome.

Comment: Hi, angular-route-segment's author here. Your jsfiddle is not working because of incorrect module dependencies. I've modified it here: http://jsfiddle.net/3boccdu6/1/ 
Now you can demonstrate your issue based on this fiddle, so that it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to your html will resolve the issue.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular-resource.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular-route.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-route-segment/1.4.0/angular-route-segment.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-animate.min.js">
</script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```